# Dockerize BlazorWasm .NET hosted project into single container?

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

## Goal

The goal is to deploy a BlazorWasm App with an integrated API (*ASP.NET Core hosted*) using **a single** docker container.

Because of the way a BlazorWasm App (.. .NET hosted) runs Client and API using the same port in IIS Express and VS, I am figuring it should be possible.

I know of the advantages of using microservices and keeping the projects apart, but that's not what I am looking for. My reasons for this being both economical and of curiosity.

**What I need help with is how to create a Dockerfile supporting this.**

## What I have tried

In an earlier project I had used 2 separate Web Apps, one for Client and one for API, **but now** I am hoping to be able to do this with a monolithic container.

Furthermore in VS Community 2019 (16.8.3) it is not possible to add Docker Support to Blazor Wasm apps (only to Blazor Server apps).

I have looked for solutions and working examples of this but having trouble finding anything helpful.

### Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Microsoft provides an image that contains the AspNetCore runtime. You can use this image as a base image for a self-designed image or you can use it directly. If you want to execute two processes in a container (Do you want to do this? - Your question is a little bit vague.), use a startup script that starts these processes as background processes and wait until they finish.

Comment: That's right two processes in a container. Blazor Wasm .net hosted in a single container and I want for a Dockerfile or method to solve this with a Dockerfile. What you suggests sounds like what I need. Do you have a link to any information that could help?

Comment: You can do it by hand (just write a shell script) or use a process control system, e.g. `supervisord`. Take a look at https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ , I think it will be helpful.